# How to reset an LG STYLO without the volume buttons

Tags: factory-reset

I broke my volume button and am unable to reset my phone how can I reset my phone with no volume keys?

Comment: Can't you do it from the settings??

Answer (score 0):

[Steps for factory reset from Settings](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-28103) :

- From any home screen, tap Apps > Settings.

  - If in tab view, tap General.
  - Under PERSONAL, tap Backup & reset.
  - Select or clear the following check boxes:

    - Back up my data
    - Automatic restore
  - Tap Backup account and follow the steps to create Google backup account, if necessary.
  - Tap Factory data reset.

    - Review the warning message and select or clear Erase SD card.
    - Tap Reset phone > Next.
    - Tap Delete all.
    - Tap OK.